# Mongolite group by/aggregate on JSON object

Tags: json, mongodb, group-by, aggregate, mongolite

I have a json document like this on my mongodb collection:
Updated document:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59da4aef8c5d757027a5a614"),
"input" : "hi",
"output" : "Hi. How can I help you?",
"intent" : "[{\"intent\":\"greeting\",\"confidence\":0.8154089450836182}]",
"entities" : "[]",
"context" : "{\"conversation_id\":\"48181e58-dd51-405a-bb00-c875c01afa0a\",\"system\":{\"dialog_stack\":[{\"dialog_node\":\"root\"}],\"dialog_turn_counter\":1,\"dialog_request_counter\":1,\"_node_output_map\":{\"node_5_1505291032665\":[0]},\"branch_exited\":true,\"branch_exited_reason\":\"completed\"}}",
"user_id" : "50001",
"time_in" : ISODate("2017-10-08T15:57:32.000Z"),
"time_out" : ISODate("2017-10-08T15:57:35.000Z"),
"reaction" : "1"
```

}

I need to perform group by on intent.intent field and I'm using Rstudio with mongolite library. 
What I have tried is :

```
pp = '[{"$unwind": "$intent"},{"$group":{"_id":"$intent.intent", "count": {"$sum":1} }}]'

stats <- chat$aggregate(
      pipeline=pp,
      options = '{"allowDiskUse":true}'
    )

print(stats)
```

But it's not working, output for above code is

```
  _id count
1  NA   727
```

Comment: I run your aggregate query over sample json document and get `{ "_id" : "greeting", "count" : 1.0 }` what is the problem?

Comment: But I'm not getting this output. I'm using Rstudio as I stated earlier and I'm still stuck at the problem. Can you tell me where do you tried this code?

Comment: I just tried your code with robomongo

Comment: Thanks for helping me so far, you were right this query is working on the document I provided, but that was only the subset of real document. I have updated the real document in the question...and on it the aggregate is not working...

Comment: the problem, intent attribute value is string not object, you need to convert the line to `"intent" : [{"intent":"greeting","confidence":0.8154089450836182}],`

Answer (score 6):

If intent attribute type is string and keep the object as string. 
We can split it to array with `\"` and use third item of array.

```
db.getCollection('test1').aggregate([
{ "$project": { intent_text : { $arrayElemAt : [ { $split: ["$intent", "\""] } ,3  ] } } },
{ "$group": {"_id": "$intent_text" , "count": {"$sum":1} }}
])
```

Result:

```
{
    "_id" : "greeting",
    "count" : 1.0
}
```